# Is a HashMap thread-safe for different keys?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, hashmap

If I have two multiple threads accessing a HashMap, but guarantee that they'll never be accessing the same key at the same time, could that still lead to a race condition?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

In @dotsid's answer he says this:

> If you change a `HashMap` in any way then your code is simply broken.

He is correct.  A `HashMap` is not thread-safe *by design*.  If it is updated without proper synchronization it may break, **even** if the threads are using disjoint sets of keys<sup>1</sup>.  Here are **just some**<sup>2</sup> of the things that can go wrong.

- If one thread does a `put`, then another thread may see a stale value for the hashmap's size.
- If one thread does a `put` with a key that is (currently) in the same hash bucket as the second thread's key, second thread's map entry might get lost, temporarily or permanently.  (This could lead to a `get` unexpectedly returning `null`, or other behavior.)  It depends on how the hash chains (or whatever) are implemented.
- When a thread does a `put` that triggers a rebuild of the table, another thread may see transient or stale versions of the hashtable array reference, its size, its contents or the hash chains.  Chaos may ensue.
- When a thread does a `put` for a key that collides with some key used by some other thread, and the latter thread does a `put` for its key, then the latter might see a stale copy of hash chain reference.  Chaos may ensue.
- When one thread probes the table with a key that collides with one of some other thread's keys, it may encounter that key on the chain.  It will call equals on that key, and if the threads are not synchronized, the equals method may encounter stale state in that key.

And if you have two threads simultaneously doing `put` or `remove` requests, there are numerous opportunities for race conditions.

I can think of three solutions:

- Use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.
- Use a regular `HashMap` but use external synchronization using primitive mutexes, `Lock` objects, and so on.  But beware that this can lead to a concurrency bottleneck due to lock contention.
- Use a different `HashMap` for each thread.  If the threads really have disjoint sets of keys, then there should be no need (from an algorithmic perspective) for them to share a single `Map`.  Indeed, if your algorithms involve the threads iterating the keys, values or entries of the map at some point, splitting the single map into multiple maps could give a significant speedup for that part of the processing.

---

<sup>1 - Even though the key sets are disjoint, keys from one set will at some point end up on the same hash chain as keys from another set.  This is unavoidable.

2 - We cannot enumerate all of the possible things that could go wrong.  For a start, we can't predict how all JVMs will handle the *unspecified* aspects of the JMM ... on all platforms.  But you should NOT be relying on that kind of information anyway.  All you need to know is that it is fundamentally wrong to use a `HashMap` like this.  An application that does this is broken ... even if you haven't observed the symptoms of the brokenness yet.</sup>

Answer (score 35):

Just use a ConcurrentHashMap. The ConcurrentHashMap uses multiple locks which cover a range of hash buckets to reduce the chances of a lock being contested. There is a marginal performance impact to acquiring an uncontested lock.

To answer your original question: According to the javadoc, as long as the structure of the map doesn't change, your are fine. This mean no removing elements at all and no adding new keys that are not already in the map. Replacing the value associated with existing keys is fine.

> If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.)

Though it makes no guarantees about visibility. So you have to be willing to accept retrieving stale associations occasionally.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you mean under "accessing". If you just reading, you can read even the same keys as long as visibility of data guarantied under "[happens-before](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html)" rules. This means that `HashMap` shouldn't change and all changes (initial constructions) should be completed before any reader start to accessing `HashMap`.

If you change a `HashMap` in any way then your code is simply broken. @Stephen C provides very good explanation why.

EDIT: If the first case is your actual situation, I recommend you to use `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` to be shure that your HashMap is never changed. Objects which are pointed by `HashMap` should not change also, so aggressive using `final` keyword can help you.

And as @Lars Andren says, `ConcurrentHashMap` is best choice in most cases.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is a best choice in my opinion. The only reason I didn't recommend it, because of author didn't ask it :)

It have less throughput because of CAS operations, but as the golden rule of concurrent programming says: "Make it right, and only then make it fast" :)

Comment: `unmodifiableMap` ensures the client cannot change the map. It does nothing to ensure that the underlying map is not changed.

Comment: As I already pointed out: "Objects which are pointed by HashMap should not change also"

Answer (score 5):

Modifying a HashMap without proper synchronization from two threads may easily lead to a race condition.

- When a `put()` leads to a resize of the internal table, this takes some time and the other thread continues to write to the old table.
- Two `put()` for different keys lead to an update of the same bucket if the keys' hashcodes are equal modulo the table size. (Actually, the relation between hashcode and bucket index is more complicated, but collisions may still occur.)

Comment: It is worse than just race conditions.  Depending on the internals of the `HashMap` implementation you are using, you can get corruption of the `HashMap` data structures, etcetera cause by memory anomalies.