# Is synchronization needed when different threads work on different keys for map?

Tags: java, dictionary, synchronization

If different threads work on different keys in the map, I think I don't need to consider synchronization.  Is this correct?

For example, my map (an ordinary HashMap) has  .  One thread is only interested in k1 and might add/update/remove/retrieve K1's value, and the other thread is only  interested in K2 and might add/update/remove/retrieve k2's value.

Comment: No it is not correct. You will need synchronization around both `get()` calls and any call that can update or clear the map, all synchronizing on the same thing. You are correct if and only if there are no concurrent updaters.

Comment: [Is a HashMap thread-safe for different keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688629/is-a-hashmap-thread-safe-for-different-keys)