# Is it safe to update a HashMap concurrently if a thread-id is a Key?

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency

I want each thread to put some data to the map where the thread-id is a key of the map. (for a multi-threading unit test)
Is it safe to put to a Map concurrently in general ?

My code looks like this.

```
public ThreadData getThreadData() {
    Long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    if( ! mutableMapRegistry.containsKey(threadId)){
        mutableMapRegistry.put(threadId, new  ThreadData());
    }

    return mutableMapRegistry.get(threadId);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a HashMap thread-safe for different keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688629/is-a-hashmap-thread-safe-for-different-keys)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you !

Comment: 'Is It safe to update a `HashMap` concurrently': no. 'If a thread-ID is a key': irrelevant.